# htaccess modrewrite without symlinks?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have always understood (unless im mistaken) that Apache's modrewrite engine requires

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

in order to work.

We have used modrewrite to hide the .php extension in addresses on a particular system in order to not reveal the chosen technology - PHP. We understand that one can still learn the server technology but you'd at least need to know how web servers work etc.

The problem is, the server tech's have brought up the risk in using +FollowSymLinks which i completely understand and agree with.

> https://serverfault.com/questions/195570/htaccess-security
>
> *[Aaron Copley](https://serverfault.com/users/50647/aaron-copley): Symlinks aren't necessarily bad but you have to have a clear understanding of your implementation of Apache. To a non-chrooted
>   Apache, symlinks certainly pose a significant risk to exposing files
>   outside of your document root.*

At the moment the system parses REQUEST_URI as such:
All rewrite rules are written to index.php

```
URL domain.com/request
REQUEST_URI = /request (trimmed as "request")
Using PHP switch () we check case 'request' : inlclude xyz.php;
exit;
```

This is a fairly common technique, but how would i implement the same result without the need for +FollowSymLinks and ***without having to go through every script in the system and change navigation links***?

Comment: This should only be a concern to you if you have actual symbolic links in your website folder that point to files in other folders. This doesn't affect the rewrite itself.

Comment: Thanks Ramengo, but what do you mean, A: I can use SymLinks with no threat to exposing files, or B: I can use modrewrite without Symlinks?

Comment: Besides, i doubt the server tech's will budge on their answer to use FollowSymLinks

Comment: You can use mod rewrite without FollowSymLinks. Are you using Symbolic Links for anything? from your example, it doesn't look like you are so this shouldn't really affect your application.

Comment: Ok cool, not using FollowSymLinks but it seems the modrewrite wasn't working (after they said no to FollowSymLinks). Maybe .htaccess is not working as a whole... I'll check quick - invoking a 500 server Error :F

Comment: Scratch what I said, check my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modrewrite will also work if you enable the following:

```
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
```

This causes Apache to check the owner of the link and the target, and only follows the link if the owners match.

Perhaps your server guys would accept that as a reduced risk?

More info here: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2004/02/19/apache_ckbk.html

Comment: Mind you, the disk I/O will go up a lot, see http://mattiasgeniar.be/2012/02/11/add-options-followsymlinks-and-avoid-options-symlinksifownermatch-in-apache-to-save-disk-io/

Comment: I noticed the comment about the kernel caching the result of the stat() and lstat() and this negating the disk I/O issue somewhat. I wonder if anybody has done any measurement of the actual impact? It would be interesting to see.

Comment: It has definitely a mesurable impact on network filesystems (such as NFS). IMHO although the Kernel caches the results it should be avoided, at some point the kernel has to refresh it's cache.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I suppose though (as I understand it) that dynamic URLs are not exactly your best friend when seeking performance anyway... although I could be mistaken. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

The Apache documentation states

> If your administrator has disabled override of FollowSymLinks for a user's directory, then you cannot use the rewrite engine. This restriction is required for security reasons.

Check this link:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks that seals it, but i still need a solution to my system... img gonna go out on a limb and answer it myself

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know im answering my own question, but im going out on a limb...

I should probably have mentioned before that the site will NOT be public as it is an administrative system so we don't care about search engines

Would i be able to do this instead of the existing implemented modrewrite:

.htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

index.php

```
header("Status: 200 OK");
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
```

I know this is messy, but we do not have time and the server tech guys will not budge, the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] should still contain the same info???

Please feel free to comment and down/upvote, but please remember i know this is extremely cowboy and it's merely a temporary workaround

**Important Note**
POST requests do NOT work this way because Apache redirects to index.php (losing the POST data) you could still use GET info

Comment: That might be the ugliest workaround I've ever seen, but it would work. I would suggest validating the uri, and using `header()` to replace the error code or redirect to an actual error page.

Comment: I know it's horrible :D but it works, amended with header() no real need to validate the URI since the switch is hard coded

Comment: Then, it's fine. For quite some time, I didn't get regexp and used to rewrite all my urls to the index and manually parse them :D